# Where in the Virtual Memory can I find x86 code compiled by .Net JIT

Tags: .net, clr, jit, ryujit

I understand that when a function is called for the first time, the JIT is invoked and it compiles the .Net IL code into x86 instruction and keeps it in the memory somewhere. 
I need to know the location where this x86 code is kept so that I can analyse the x86 assembly instructions(the purpose is not really important in the context of this question.)
Can anyone tell me how one would determine the memory location at which the translated code is stored, or probably which function in JIT code does that. I have the JIT code with me(as .net source code is published in GitHub but I am overwhelmed by the size of the code so far). I would appreciate any sort of help. Thanks in advance...

It would help if someone could suggest a dissassembler which could give x86 assembly instruction dump of a running .net exe, much like visual studio dissassembler does but I need to run it automatically. I know that this can be done statically by ngen. ngen could convert to x86 instructions and then any dissassembler can get the dump, but its important for me that this has to be done after the exe is run.

This is because the reason why I need the x86 instruction dump is to find similarity between multiple .net exes. The challenge with directly looking at statically dissassembled assembly is that it could be packed or obfuscated in which case they might look dissimilar even though they are internally similar. But at runtime they will be unpacked/deobfuscated by the packer program and the JIT compiled x86 instructions would look similar.

Comment: Why do you need the memory location? Why not look at the `Dissasembly` window in Visual Studio?

Comment: Removing the reference to `[Java]` because this question is about .NET

Comment: That is not generally possible, the address is highly random and never repeats.   An anti-malware feature.  Only a profiler has a shot at it.  Avoid asking an XY question, "analyse" does not mean anything and it is in fact essential in this context.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If I can get the x86 dissassembly of the entire exe, that would be good enough, but I will need it to be done without manual intervention. This is because I will be running this in a Sandbox with several .net files and comparing their x86 assembly code.  Is it possible with any tool including Visual Studio to get the x86 dissassembly automatically?

Comment: @HansPassan Actually I need to look at the x86 assembly instructions that would be generated after JIT compilation. This is to find similarity between multiple .net exes. The challenge with directly looking at .net IL is that it could be packed or obfuscated in which case they might look dissimilar even though they are internally similar. But after JIT compilation, their x86 instructions would look similar even though they are packed or obfuscated previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [debugger api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397953%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to read the jitted instructions from the process. (Specifically, a combination of [ICorDebugFunction::GetNativeCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [ICorDebugCode2::GetCodeChunks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230245%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ICorDebugProcess::ReadMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Doing things this way would probably require that the method has already been jitted ... but you could probably arrange for that using [ICorDebugEval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230832%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (perhaps with a breakpoint at the start of the method and then aborting the eval when it's hit).

Comment: I am just starting to follow this approach so dont know wether Ill be successful or not. But  looks like this can really do the job for me. Thank you so much.